# Use different providers in Web.Config - Devart to ODP.NET

Tags: web-config, odp.net, connector, devart

I was using Devart in my Web.Config. I have migrated to ODP 12.2.11 and I am trying to use a role and membership manager provider different from the ODP provider since it changes my tables and procedures. Is it possible to do this?

My DB connection is correct with the new Oracle Connector, but I can't use the other provider.

I tried to use the older Devart provider ONLY for the membership and rolemanager and i got an error like "cant connect to database".

And i tried to use the nugget System.Web.Providers 1.2 and i got another error. (The error is like the entity framework cant mapping the properties, nothing important)

Comment: Please contact us via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html and specify dotConnect for Oracle-specific error with its stack trace and attach a small test project for reproducing the issue.